# In Tableau CRM, how do we implement Fixed LOD like in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-crm, tableau

Example of the Tableau custom field:
sum({fixed [opportunity_id] , [booking_type]: AVG([booking_amount])})

What is the equivalent of Fixed LOD so that we can replicate the above in Tableau CRM?